# Let EF generate custom IDs defined by content of specific fields of related table

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2022, code-first, jetbrains-rider, c#-11.0

To validate entries of a specific table, but mainly to reduce number of entries, I thought about let EF generate custom IDs for this specific table, as follows:

```
class TrainingTimeDefinition
{
    public string Id { get; set; }  // automatically generated: [this.WeekDay] + [this.StartTime] + [this.Period]
    public DayOfWeek WeekDay { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly StartTime { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan Period { get; set; }
}
```

But it seems not to be as easy to implement in .NET core as with Jakarta/JPA. In my example above I left separators between WeekDays and e.g. StartTime, this just to reduce magnitude of my questions - as I saw that event this detail let programmers struggle and therefore ask questions in StackOverflow.

So about how to implement I found this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5303  and [Can I store enums as strings in EF 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179444/can-i-store-enums-as-strings-in-ef-5)

Relating to the second link: To make my questions easier, please don't consider if WeekDay might be "Monday" or "1". For the purpose of this thread it does not matter.

- Is it really such an effort to get it done, so it is better to avoid
  solving it via EF? In other words: Do I ask the right question?
- I am new with EF. Is there a easier way to achieve it, letting EF
  create custom string-IDs like this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the desired ID? Is the int Id always increasing, or only counting up if Weekday and StartTime are the same? How does this help you to reduce the number of entries?

Comment: You are right, JineappleAra. I modified class above. So I think it is more clear why such a custom Id reduces number of entries - especially as I deleted the part counting up an integer.  Purpose of my solution are calendars of a sports club, where database just stores differend types of calendar entries (in my example for traininig times), and all the rest of this calendar will be mainly done at the front end.

Comment: To make it more clear, let assume property StartTime will contain values difined in clear 5-minutes-steps, such as 12:00, 12:05 ... - meaning without seconds and further fractions of a second.

Comment: Use [Computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns). | Indexes can be made on computed columns, but there are certain limitations that depend on the DBMS you use. For example, [Limitations and Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16#Limitations) in Sql Server.

Comment: Thanks! I think computet colums can be a possible solution to my problem. I would like you to grant you that point. Can you write me an formal anwer therefor?

Comment: In your case you want the ID to be generated based on a set of properties (WeekDay, StartTime and Period). EF Core does not directly support composite primary keys that are not backed by separate key properties in entity classes.